# What is the network layer in which RLPx is used for peering in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, devp2p, rlpx

**We had a question from our client as such they need to know in which Network layer is the RLPx protocol being used for the peering process**

I have got to know that peering process happens using RLPx protocol, which is a TCP based protocol, but the question is like in which network layer(out of 7 layers in TCP) is the RLPx protocol used?

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RLPx is a cryptographic peer-to-peer network and protocol suite which provides a general-purpose transport and interface for applications to communicate via a p2p network.
Since it is a TCP-based Transport Protocol, it means it is on the Transport layer.

Read about [The RLPx Transport Protocol here](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md)

Also there is a similar question on [stackoverflow in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029311/what-is-the-use-of-ethereums-rlpx-and-how-do-they-use-it-in-ethereum-ecosystem) that can help you. Read it's first answer.